# Laravel get value from db with columns key/value

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent, controller

I have a table on my DB with these columnns:

```
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name            | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| value           | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I would access to value values by name.

For example I have these datas:

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id | name       | value      |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 | start_date | 2020-01-01 |
|  2 | end_date   | 2021-01-01 |
+----+------------+------------+
```

I would to get '2020-01-01' by 'start_date'.

I tried this code, but I'm not satisfyed because with this code I get all values of the row, not only the value expected.

```
Configuration::get()->keyBy('start_date');
```

I'm not sure I was clear.

Let me know.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: What have you tried? I'm not seeing any Models or Queries or anything in your question... On Stackoverflow, you're expected to make an effort to solve you own problem, and we'll assist with debugging your approach.

Comment: @TimLewis I added my code. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: No problem! Next step, just a quick explanation on why that code doesn't work :) What does it do vs what you're expecting it to do. At a glance, maybe `Configuration::pluck('name', 'value')` might work (or `::pluck('value', 'name')`, not sure on the order)

Comment: Thanks for your example, but I don't know how to get value, could you please explain it to me?

Comment: Using the code I posted, you should end up with a Collection like this: `['start_date' => '2020-01-01', 'end_date' => '2021-01-01']`, so if you did  `$keyVals = Configuration::pluck('value', 'name');`, then you'd be able to access it like `$keyVals['start_date']` (`'2020-01-01'`) and `$keyVals['end_date']` (`'2021-01-01'`). Is that what you're looking for? If not, then I really don't understand your question...

Comment: I think it could be good for me! I will try in my code :) Thanks in advance

Comment: @TimLewis I tested the code and it is perfect! Please, write it on answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to get an array of key/value pairs, and each key in the `name` column is unique, you can simply use `pluck()` (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck):

```php
$configuration = Configuration::pluck('value', 'name');
dd($configuration);
// ['start_date' => '2020-01-01', 'end_date' => '2021-01-01']
```

Then, you'd use simply array access to use these configuration settings where applicable:

```php
$startDate = $configuration['start_date']; // '2020-01-01'
$endDate = $configuration['end_date'];     // '2021-01-01'
...
```